# Azure Stream Analytics - First after x minutes from current

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

In a select I need to get the first row after 15 min from the current.

I was trying to do this the following way

Note: before this i do a TIMESTAMP By a.timestamp

Select

```
SELECT Lag(a) Over (Partition By a.imdate Limit Duration(hour, 12) When a.timestamp < DATEADD(minute, -15, System.Timestamp))
From a
```

My issue is that System.Timestamp has the value of the event being observed by lag and not the one being observed outside, resulting in null.

So, in a sample of

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:30:05.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:16:03.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:03:02.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  }
]
```

I would like the lag to provide me the 3rd event when looking at both the first and second.

but, in a sample of

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:30:05.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:24:03.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:23:02.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  }
]
```

I would like the lag to provide me null for all of them.

or, in a sample of

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:55:05.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:24:03.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-14T08:23:02.571Z",
    "imdate": 96699
  }
]
```

I would like the lag to provide me 2nd event when observing the first but null when observing the 2nd.

So basically, the first event to happen after the last 15min.

Any idea on how i can achieve this?

Comment: Hi, by default the stream of data will be processed by arrival time. In order to use the timestamp in the message you can use TIMESTAMP BY [timestamp] in your example. In this case, you can then define the "out of order" buffer in the settings so your event stream will be automatically reordered and the LAG command will automatically take this order. We described all the time management concepts in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-out-of-order-and-late-events

Comment: Hello @Jean-Sébastien, I already do the TIMESTAMP BY message.timestamp.